# How to sort pointers in vector but not sort original elements [C++]

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to implement an application which will find all minimal spanning trees in graph but I'm not familiar with C++.

I have a vector G with elements <int, int, int> which are weight, edgeStart, edgeDest:
`vector<pair<int, edge>> G;` and the edge is:
`#define edge pair<int, int>`

Now I have a problem because I want to have another vector S with pointers to elements of vector G. Then I want to SORT that vector S (by weight increasing) but I don't want to sort original elements of vector G (I just want the vector G to be unchanged).

Is that even possible?

tl;dr:

vector G: <int, int, int> -------> UNSORTED and CONST

vector S: pointers_to_elements_of_G -------> SORTED

Comment: `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<std::pair<int, edge>>> S;`?

Comment: this is much easier if you try something, write some code, and then, no matter how broken your code is you can post it and we can help to fix it. Currently this question seems to be merely based on a false premise. If you store pointers in a second container and sort that container it does not affect order of the original vector.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't `#define edge`. Make a proper typedef: `using edge = std::pair<int, int>;`

Comment: in different, more snarky, words: Yes it is possible. Does that answer your question? ;). You'll need a custom comparator for `std::sort` that does not compare the pointers but the objects they point to. Rearranging the pointers in `S` will not change order in `G`.

Comment: I'm using Kruskal algorithm on second vector (S) and it works but after finding all edges included in minimal spanning trees I need to change original graph. I need to add boolean to every edge informing if edge is included or not. Something like this:
edge1: YES, edge2: YES, edge3: NO, edge4: YES. My current Vector S is using COPIES of Vector G elements. Now I want to use pointers because it ll make my app faster. I'm not posting my app because it's too large and I want to know just that thing.

Comment: please read about [mcve]. We need not see your whole app. That would most likely be too much code and nobody would read it all. Instead you should create a toy example that has only the code to demonstrate your current issue. It needs not be more than ~5 lines of code. Create one vector, create a second vector with pointers, call `std::sort`, print the elements of both to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example, but can be extended to your use case by replacing
the second int with edge.  In c++ a simple using statement is better than macro definition:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
  using pair_i = std::pair<int, int>;
  std::vector<pair_i> v {{10,1},{1,2},{2,2},{4,8}};
  std::vector<const pair_i*> v_p(v.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v_p[i] = &(v[i]);
  std::sort(v_p.begin(), v_p.end(), [&](auto& p1, auto& p2){ return std::get<0>(*p1) < std::get<0>(*p2);});
  //printing to stdout to show one is sorted and the other is untouched
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    auto& p = v[i];
    auto& p_p = *(v_p[i]);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(p) << "," << std::get<1>(p) << ", "
              << std::get<0>(p_p) << "," << std::get<1>(p_p) << "\n";
 }
}
```